# Transpose four lists of data into two lists for use in List Plot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, functional

I have four lists of data

```
x1 = {1,3,5,7}
y1 = {0,2,4,6}

x2 = {10,12,14,16}
y2 = {8,10,12,14}
```

In one line is it possible to use transpose to get two lists which can be passed to ListPlot for plotting? What would I do if I had 100 lists I wanted to combine in this same way?  Below is my attempt, but it doesn't quite work.

```
data = Transpose[{#1, #2}] & @@ {{x1, 
y1}, {x2, y2}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pardon me if I misunderstand but is this all you want?

```
ListPlot[Transpose /@ {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}]
```

[image]

Or maybe you are looking for the single function form:

```
Transpose[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}, {1, 3, 2}]   (* thanks for the correction belisarius *)
```

> ```
> {{{1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {7, 6}},
>  {{10, 8}, {12, 10}, {14, 12}, {16, 14}}}
> ```

Comment: `ListLinePlot@Transpose[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}, {1, 3, 2}]` ?

Comment: @belisarius Oh, I guess I just messed up.  Thanks for the pointer. :-/

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yeah, thats all I wanted.  Is it possible to do this with a pure function like I was trying to do?

Comment: @olliepower What is the purpose of introducing `Function` when you can use `Transpose` directly?  Do you mean is there a solution *without* transpose?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard practically speaking, your solution is much better than introducing `Function`.  The reason I am curious is because my attempt at doing this with a pure function shows that I'm not very adept at mapping the function across lists, and this is an important skill to master for functional style programming.

Comment: @olliepower Well your code *would* work with a single character change, which is to change `@@` to `@@@`, giving `Apply` at level one rather than level zero: `Transpose[{#1, #2}] & @@@ {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}`.  However this is a rather round-about way to go as you first disassemble each list and then put it back together *in the same order*, *then* `Transpose`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks!  Your version is MUCH more readable and it makes more sense to me. Also thanks for humoring my silly mistake.